# How do I use Mac keyboard output in an iOS app

Tags: ios, macos, keyboard

I recently got an M1 MacBook and voila, my iOS apps run on it. There are interesting problems though.  One is using the Mac keyboard.

I notice that if a UITextField or UITextView is first responder, the Mac's keyboard output is surprisingly not used.  But there are cases in my app though where I want to use the Mac keyboard output without one of these controls being first responder. How do I receive these keystrokes as events/messages in iOS?